# How to count number of function calls in Erlang?

Tags: function, indexing, erlang, counter

I have one function on my Erlang server which posts data to web service. This web service requires the counter (how much times it was called). I don't really know why they need it but it's crucial.

I can't use the external DB for some reasons. So I need to have some global variable stored on the server permanently. I thought about saving counter to a file, extracting and incrementing it every time function is called.

Is there more efficient way to achieve my goal?

**EDIT**
The function may be called from many different clients at the same time, so this adds another problem: If 3 clients call the function simultaneously, function will increment the counter only once and I will get an error. How do I make the function wait for another one to finish and then execute?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: More efficient would be to read the counter at startup and store it in ETS (or a stateful process), and then write it back at shutdown. However: this is not 100% reliable. What happens if you "forget" about a number of calls and try calling with an earlier number?

Comment: The web service will return some kind of error and the following calls will make no sense. This is why it's so crucial to keep the counter right.

Comment: Will the function ever be called concurrently (from > 1 Erlang processes)? In that case storing the data in a file can cause race conditions.

Comment: @Dogbert please see the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If 3 clients call the function simultaneously, function will increment the counter only once and I will get an error. How do I make the function wait for another one to finish and then execute?

I would use a simple counter built with `gen_server` and only access the counter on the disk from it. Using a `gen_server` like this would ensure you never get a file access race condition.

Here's something to get you started:

```
-module(file_counter).
-export([start_link/0, start/0, increment/0]).
-behaviour(gen_server).
-export([init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2, terminate/2, code_change/3]).

start_link() ->
    gen_server:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, [], []).

start() ->
    gen_server:start({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, [], []).

increment() ->
    gen_server:call(?MODULE, increment).

init([]) ->
    {ok, "file_counter.txt"}.

handle_call(increment, _From, File) ->
    Counter = case file:read_file(File) of
        {ok, Binary} -> binary_to_integer(Binary);
        {error, enoent} -> 0
    end,
    ok = file:write_file(File, integer_to_binary(Counter + 1)),
    {reply, Counter, File}.

handle_cast(_Req, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

handle_info(_Info, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

terminate(_Reason, _State) ->
    ok.

code_change(_OldVsn, State, _Extra) ->
    {ok, State}.
```

Demo:

```
1> c(file_counter).
{ok,file_counter}
2> file_counter:start_link().
{ok,<0.40.0>}
3> file_counter:increment().
0
4> file_counter:increment().
1
5> file_counter:increment().
2
6> [ spawn_link(file_counter, increment, []) || _ <- lists:seq(1, 9998) ].
[<0.45.0>,<0.46.0>,<0.47.0>,<0.48.0>,<0.49.0>,<0.50.0>,
 <0.51.0>,<0.52.0>,<0.53.0>,<0.54.0>,<0.55.0>,<0.56.0>,
 <0.57.0>,<0.58.0>,<0.59.0>,<0.60.0>,<0.61.0>,<0.62.0>,
 <0.63.0>,<0.64.0>,<0.65.0>,<0.66.0>,<0.67.0>,<0.68.0>,
 <0.69.0>,<0.70.0>,<0.71.0>,<0.72.0>,<0.73.0>|...]
7> file_counter:increment().
10001
```

Just call `file_counter:increment()` before making each call and use the value returned by it as the count.

Edit: This is just a quick module I wrote. You should probably make the file name configurable by passing it to `start`, `start_link`, and `init`, as well as not register the process with a name if you want to be able to run multiple copies of the counter. The code here is really a POC to get you started.

(On a system with an SSD disk, I was able to execute `file_counter:increment()` about 5000 times per second.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm really new to Erlang and before I read doc about gen:server, will it save the counter in case the server crushes or the power will go off?

Comment: The code I posted will write the counter to the file before every call to `increment` returns. If your program crashes / power goes off after `increment` returns and before you make the web service request, the counter will not rollback, no.